# Careers 2.0 - Profile field for gear

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think the Editor field is a great idea, right along with the technologies that we like / dislike. I would like to propose a similar field about favorite gear (keyboard, mouse, screen). I'm thinking of it as a way to learn about fellow coders, not as a signal for employers.